# Android Wifi signal icons

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-icons

Is there a way to get the icon used by the system for the Wifi strength signal (I haven't found them anywhere..)? I want them to create a custom Wifi Manager for my application.

It would be really useful to have also the layout assets if they are available (no idea however of where I can look for taking them :( ).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get then and all the **material design icons** at the material design resources on *github* [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons), they are under the *device section*. You can also refer to the icons and their locations by this link [here](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) to better navigate through the folders. 
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the default material design icons from https://www.google.com/design/icons/

Just choose the icon, size, and color you want then download as PNGs which will give you the icon for all the screen resolutions needed for android, ios and web.

Comment: Amazing way to do it, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Vector Drawable with available android icons in Android studio
[image]

and then choose clipart:

[image]